# Multiple submit buttons on Kendo Form

Tags: javascript, reactjs, kendo-ui

Is it possible to have multiple submit buttons, each of them calling another function in Kendo?

For example I have a form like this:

```
<Form
      onSubmit={handleSubmit}
      render={(formRenderProps) => (
        <FormElement
          style={{
            maxWidth: 650,
          }}
        >
          <fieldset className={"k-form-fieldset"} style={{marginTop:'2vh'}}>
            <legend className={"k-form-legend"}>
              Atributes:
            </legend>
            <div className="mb-3">
            {tempAtr.map((data) => 
              <Field
                name={data.naziv}
                component={ data.id === 1 ?Input: 
          data.id === 2 ?Input: 
          data.id === 3 ?DatePicker: 
          data.id === 4 ?Input:
          data.id === 5 ?Input:
          data.id === 6 ?DropDownList:
          data.id === 7 ?DropDownList:
          data.id === 8 ?MultiSelect:
          data.id === 9 ?MultiSelect:
         Input}
                label={data.name}
              />)}
            </div>
          </fieldset>
          <div className="k-form-buttons">
            <Button
              type={"submit"}
              className='appBar-containers'
              disabled={!formRenderProps.allowSubmit}
            >
              Save
            </Button>
            <Button
              type={"submit"}
              className='appBar-containers'
              disabled={!formRenderProps.allowSubmit}
            >
              Start
            </Button>
          </div>
        </FormElement>
      )}
    />
```

So when I click Save, it goes to SaveFunction, and when I click Start, it goes to StartFunction. Any help would be very appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

If anybody is looking for an answer, I did it this way. Added an id to each of the buttons:

```
<Button id='SaveButton'>Save</Button>
<Button id='StartButton'>Start</Button>
```

and in the onSubmit function added this:

```
const handleSubmit = (dataItem,event) => 
    {
      if(event.nativeEvent.submitter.id=='StartButton')
      {
        startSession(dataItem);
      }
      else
      {
        saveChanges(dataItem);
      }
        
    };
```